# finding cells having superscript and subscript text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn VBA.

I want to mark the cells having *superscript/subscript* in the cell text. Is this possible using Excel VBA?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198232.aspx

Comment: Have a look at the [Macro Recorder](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/8204/how-to-record-a-macro) in Excel to find out how to do something with VBA. If you are a beginner with VBA I also recommend to read the [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices) guide and follow these rules from beginning on.

Comment: @Peh, I have some knowledge of VBA, I just cant get how to know if a cell contain SUP or SUB character formatting & at which character indexes?

Comment: You need to check this setting `.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.Subscript = True` for each character (with a loop looping through all characters) in a cell to find out if any character is superscript formatted. If you need to do this with multiple cells you will need another loop around this.

Answer (score 2):

If your cells are either

- all superscript, or
- start with a superscript character (which is quirky - `xlPart` should find any part of a formatted string)

then this code (setup to look at column B) will be much faster than testing every character in very cell as per the msft link

You would use `Application.FindFormat.Font.Superscript = True` for superscript

Failing this I would look at more complex solution to parse out these characters which would require exporting the text.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim rng3 As Range
    Dim FirstAddress As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("B:B")


    Application.FindFormat.Font.Subscript = True


    With rng1
        Set rng2 = .Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, , , True)

        If rng2 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "None found"
        Else
            FirstAddress = rng2.Address
            Set rng3 = rng2
            Do
                Set rng2 = .Cells.Find("*", rng2, xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlNext, , , True)
                If rng2.Address = FirstAddress Then
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    Set rng3 = Union(rng3, rng2)
                End If
            Loop
            If Not rng3 Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng3.Address
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This works (for me) only with fully formatted cells (as if `xlPart` did not help). It is also almost required to precede with `Application.FindFormat.Clear` before setting a new format, to avoid merging the new format with previous settings. +1 though for paving the way.